# bash execute command in string from input?

Tags: bash

I've run into a problem where I'm unable to execute a command in a string thats read in from a file. I'm executing the following code:

```
red=`tput setaf 1`
reset=`tput sgr0`
string=$(sed "${line_num}q;d" $file)
printf "%s" "$string"
```

Edit: for clarity, the string in `$file` at `line_num` is `${red}tin2${reset}`

and the output I get is:

```
${red}tin2${reset}
```

If I instead do `string="${red}tin2${reset}"` the output will simply by `tin2` (in red text color). So I'm not sure why the ${red} isn't executing in my first case when it seems its being stored the same in the string.

Comment: Add **exec $string** after the printf line.

Comment: Doesn't work: line 14: exec: ${red}tin2${reset}: not found

Comment: Sorry,  i meant **eval** I was thinking in perl, which is very similar.

Comment: `printf "$string"` is what you want, assume that `$string` does not contain any `printf` format conversion.

Comment: `eval $string` gave the following error: `line 14: $'\E[31mtin2\E[m\017': command not found`. and `printf "$string"` gave the same output mentioned in the question: `${red}tin2${reset}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, found an ugly solution. Make the `printf "%s" "$string"` a string and `eval` that string.

```
red=`tput setaf 1`
reset=`tput sgr0`
string=$(sed "${line_num}q;d" $file)
string2="printf \"%s\" \"$string\""
eval $string2
```